# SwiftUI Sending Parameters To SecondView

Tags: swift, swiftui

Hello there i am trying to learn SwiftUI and my version is 16.0 i have a problem with transferring data between two pages. My situation is i want a list which contains my elements like : Image, Text etc. then when user clicks to an item. I want to send him or her detail page which gives selected item : Image, Text. I hope i clarified my problem with my explanation.

First of all Here is my list and list item :

```
struct WebViewCard: View {
@EnvironmentObject var dataManager : DataManager
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss


var body: some View {
    List { 
        ForEach(dataManager.zodiacNews, id: \.id){ zodiacNews in
            
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading,content: {
                    
                    WebImage(url: URL(string: zodiacNews.image))
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 170)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .shadow(radius: 10)
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                        Text(zodiacNews.title)
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text(zodiacNews.subTitle)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .lineLimit(2)
                            .frame(height: 40)
                    }
                }).shadow(color: Color(red:0,green: 0,blue: 0,opacity: 0.3), radius: 3,x: 6,y: 6)
            }
        }
    }.background {
        Color.white
    }.navigationTitle("Burçlar")
    
    
}
}
```

Second page is where i am putting this view :

```
struct OpenWebPageList: View {
@EnvironmentObject var dataManager : DataManager
var body: some View {
    
    let allNews = self.dataManager.zodiacNews
    NavigationView {
        NavigationLink(destination: OpenWebPage(news: allNews)){
                WebViewCard()
            }
            
    }
}}
```

Third one will be My Detail View ->

```
struct OpenWebPage: View {
var news : [BurcWebViewDataClass]
var body: some View {
    ForEach(news) { news in
        Text(news.title)
    } 
}}
```

and finally my datamanager code is below:

```
class DataManager : ObservableObject {
@Published var zodiacs : [ZodiacData] = []
@Published var zodiacNews : [BurcWebViewDataClass] = []

init(){
    fetchZodiacNews()
}

func fetchZodiacNews(){
    zodiacNews.removeAll()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let ref = db.collection("BurcHaberleri")
    ref.getDocuments{ snapshot, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        if let snapshot = snapshot{
            for document in snapshot.documents{
                let data = document.data()
                let id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
                let url = data["url"] as? String ?? ""
                let image = data["image"] as? String ?? ""
                let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
                let subTitle = data["subTitle"] as? String ?? ""
                
                
                let zodiacNews = BurcWebViewDataClass(id: id, url: url, image: image, title: title, subTitle: subTitle)
                self.zodiacNews.append(zodiacNews)
                
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

with this coode if user clicks on any item which is in the list. User will see all the items from my firebase-firestore. So i want to resolve this problem. Any help will be preciated.

Comment: You only have a link from your second view to your first view but nothing from the first to the third one. You need NavigationLink components inside the List in your first view. And I must say I don’t understand why you even need the second view, why not go directly to the first view?

Comment: when you explained like this. I solved my question btw. I was confused i guess when i was coding. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)